# Taming Xcode Storyboards

Tags: xcode, xcode4, uistoryboard

I've inherited a project that uses ~100 Xcode storyboard scenes. Trying to add to this project has been a nightmare for the following reasons:

- My machine (late 2011 Macbook Pro 13inch with non-SSD drive 16GB running 10.8 + XCode 4.4) crawls to a halt on storyboards. In some cases I'll move a scene and it will take 10 seconds to update its position.
- When I modify a scene (create a segue between two scenes, etc) in some cases all the scenes disappear. I have to do a "select all" on the sidebar to get them back.
- Navigating a specific storyboard scene is absolutely frustrating.  There's no apparent way to sort the storyboard scenes by name.
- The filter feature below the scenes sidebar kind of lets me find the scene I'm looking for, but has the frustrating side effect of filtering out the attributes (segues, views, etc) of the specific scene I'm looking for. So if I need to modify the "add_new_guy" segue for "Person View Controller", and I type "Person" in the filter, I get the Person View Controller sans the add_new_guy segue. If I delete the text in the filter to make the segue appear, I'm taken back to the top of the scene list and (most likely) away from the Person View Controller at the other end of it. I end up scrolling all the way down the scene list manually looking for the specific scene I want to change.

I've spent hours googling solutions and nothing useful has appeared. Any suggestions on how to improve the storyboards situation or pointers to things in XCode I've stupidly overlooked?

Disclaimers:

a) I am well aware that moving to nibs would solve the problem and 100 storyboard scenes is nuts, but I've inherited the code and I'm expected to do storyboards for at least the next year.

b) I'm aware that it's possible to split out the project into several storyboards. I might look into this if I have time.

c) I've heard that some problems may be caused by having two storyboards open at once, which I've tried to avoid as much as possible.

d) Filing a bug with Apple's regarding storyboards is already on my to-do list.

Comment: wow 100 storyboards, that's insane! Sorry to hear about this. If you came up with any solutions or workarounds for this, it might be good to add an answer to the question for any others who run into such a horrendous problem.

Answer (score 2):

First, work on splitting your storyboard up into smaller storyboards.  I would recommend a maximum of 4-5 view controllers per storyboard.  It will be a giant headache at first, just work on it over time.  Take a look at [RBStoryboardLink](https://github.com/rob-brown/RBStoryboardLink), which allows you to connect them "by allowing 'pseudo-segues' between UIStoryboards. These segues can be built without leaving Interface Builder and without writing any extra code".  This will give you:

1. The ability to make abstract super classes in storyboards for very similar view controllers
2. Smaller, more manageable files that don't bring your computer to a halt
3. Fewer merge conflicts when working as part of a team (assuming your project is under version control)

Second, tell your boss to immediately purchase you a new, way better development computer.  They'll make back the $3-$4k in more efficient development time in a matter of days.  (Or, if this is contract work… buy a new one yourself.)

And, please indulge my slightly off-topic comment.

Regarding this statement:

> I'm expected to do storyboards for at least the next year

Work expectations are always negotiable.  Your boss likely thinks "switching from storyboards to code will cost more time than it will save."  If this isn't true, say so.